# Can I overlay text on a sprite image?

Tags: jquery, css, sprite

This is really a **two part question**.  I'm struggling with two problems that I can't figure out.

**Question #1**. Why does my sprite image show both images.  I would expect it to show the bottom one and then on a mouse over show the top one. I've posted a screenshot of what is showing up.  Below is both my HTML and css style I'm using.  The sprite image is 50x40.

[image]
[image]

HTML

```
<li>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <div class="image-options">
            <a href="#" class="likeButton" title="Like image"><span>Like</span></a>
        </div>
        <a href="/view_profile.php?id=5693">
            <img src="photos/files/5693/grid/e1cd6ee3042f35dc7a538a5e516507e3.jpeg" />
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.image-wrapper {
position : relative;
display  : inline-block;
}

image-wrapper img {
position : relative;
}

.image-wrapper .image-options {
position : absolute;
top      : 0;
right    : 0;
left     : 0;
height   : 40px;
z-index  : 2;
display  : none;
background : #eeeeee;

zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=90);
opacity: 0.9;
}

.image-options .likeButton {
display: block;
width: 50px;
height: 40px;
border-right: 1px solid #dedede;
background: url('/bootstrap/img/like.png') bottom;
text-indent: -99999px;
}

.likeButton:hover {
background-position: 0 0;
}
```

**Question #2**. Why isn't my text

> Like

showing up?  I'm trying to show it centered above the sprite image.

Any thoughts what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Use background image on hyper links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `.image-wrapper .image-options` is `40px` high - so it will show the whole sprite. To show only the half you have to change its height to `20px`
2. Your `.image-options .likeButton` has a `text-indent: -9999px` - that's why the `Like` text is hidden

Comment: That was the issue but if I shorten my height to 20px the sprite shows correctly but my border on the right shows only 20px (half way down)

Comment: The easiest solution is to revert your height to `40px` and make your sprite `80px` high with blank spaces between the images

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an image tag directly, why not set the parent hyperlink with that background image?

```
<a href="#" class="likeButton" title="Like image">Like</a>   
<a href="/view_profile.php?id=5693" class="somethingelse">
   <br/>
</a>


 .likeButton{
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xANmb.png');
    text-align: center;
    verticle-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: grey;
}
.likeButton:hover{
    background-position: 0px -20px
}
.somethingelse{
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAKId.jpg');
    text-align: center;
    verticle-align: middle;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -10px -60px;
    /*background-size: 45px 45px;*/
}
```

Any text will be able to go anywhere over any image.
Background image size and positions can be set also.

I added an example to play with:  http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/wtKzc/23/

hth.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer #1**

You have

```
.image-wrapper .image-options {
  display  : none;
}
```

so the icon is not shown. Changing it to `display:block` works for me with another image.
Maybe you have to set

```
.image-options .likeButton {
  height: 40px;
}
```

to `height: 20px;` in order to cut your image, I don't know.

**Answer #2**

"Like" is not showing up because of

```
.image-options .likeButton {
  text-indent: -99999px;
}
```

you should remove that line.